# Dismiss dialog when click on dialog itself

Tags: android

I have a dialog in my app, which contain views.How will i dismiss my dialog,when i click on it?
It not necessarily on click is on views, but anywhere in dialog.
 Need complete procedure.I searched for hour, but either its view on click solution or outside dialog click solution. So suggest solution to Dismiss dialog when click in dialog area.

Comment: try calling `dismiss()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello please try this :

```
  AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog(getActivity()){

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            dismiss();
            return false;
        }
    };

    dialog.setView(yourView);

    dialog.show();
```